# Set maximum Flash cache size for Chrome/Chromium/YandexBrowser (Pepper Data\Shockware Flash)

Tags: google-chrome, flash, chromium, browser-cache, yandex-browser

Cleaning up the disk, I found out that the folder `c:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Yandex\YandexBrowser\User Data\Default\Pepper Data\Shockwave Flash` has grown to `22 GB` (!) over time.

(Yandex Browser is Chromium-based and according to my research, the folder structure in Chromium and Chrome in this case is the same.)

According to https://mybroadband.co.za/vb/showthread.php/530504-Chrome-was-using-4-5-GB-storage-on-my-machine-without-cleaning-it-up , I can safely delete everything in it.

But that's not good enough. I wish to fix the problem once and for all by setting the cache size limit so that this never happens again.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>(Nor do I wish to resort to workarounds like creating a scheduled task to clean it unless there are no other options. From my experience, there should be: every browser-like program worth speaking of that uses a cache of potentially unlimited size provides some way to set a limit.)</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lies in the [Flash Player Administration Guide](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/flashplayer/articles/flash_player_admin_guide/pdf/flash_player_23_0_admin_guide.pdf).

According to it, one can create a settings file `mms.cfg` in the `Pepper Data\Shockwave Flash\System` directory (the `System` directory didn't exist in my case so I created it). With the following contents:

```
AssetCacheSize = <max cache size in MB>
```

(the default is `0`, meaning unlimited).